# How to calculate a percentile based on race position where 1st place should equal 100%

Tags: t-sql, percentage

I have a table with Raceid, OverallPosition int and OverallCompetitors int.

How do i calculated a percentage for each competitor where 1st place = 100% and last is > 0%

Comment: This is not a complete question, because you did not include any sample, or the expected output.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

OverallPercentileCalc = 100 - (cast(OverallPosition - 1 as decimal(10,4)) / cast(OverallCompetitors as decimal(10,4)) * 100)